# trying to plot time in bokeh y axis

Tags: python, mysql, eclipse, plot, bokeh

I am trying to plot the time on my y axis in bokeh. The data is being read through my mySQL server and the time that I am trying to plot is a varchar in my database. I cannot change the time to datetime because of the way the database has been set up. Everytime I plot the graph, the y axis shows time in microseconds. I tried using the DatetimeTickFormatter to change it to minutes but it doesn't change and also shows no line on the plot. Could you tell me how to change the microsecond time to minutes?

```
p.line(x, y, color ='red', line_width=2)
p.yaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(seconds = ['%Ss'],
                                      minsec = [':%M:%S'],
                                      minutes = [':%M', '%Mm'],
                                      hourmin = ['%H:%M'],
                                      hours = ['%Hh', '%H:%M'])
'# show the results
```

`output_file(".html"
show(p)`

[Output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRvJo.png)

Comment: What hinders you to convert y to a DateTimeIndex? df['y'] = pd.to_datetime(df['y'])

Comment: because my y input is only a time and does not include a date so if I do the above it gives me an error saying 'day is out of range for month' @mc51

Comment: Can you try specifying datetime in your `figure` object?  That is try your `DatetimetickFormatter` in conjunction with `p = figure( . . ., y_axis_type="datetime")`